# How to pass VB.Net string to C++ dll as char*?

Tags: c++, string, vb.net, dllimport

My VB.Net program is running on a Win CE device and using a C++ dll from the manufacturer, to use the attached printer.

Their documentation lists the function call like so:

```
int Prn_Str(char *fmt, …);
```

And their sample app using the dll is written in C++. Here's a sample of a call:

```
rc =  Prn_Str((char*)"POS签购单/POS SALES SLIP\n");
```

So in my code I declare the function:

```
<DllImport("VAx_VPOS396_APPAPI.dll", EntryPoint:="Prn_Str", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> _
    Private Shared Function Prn_Str(ByVal txt As String) As Integer
    End Function
```

And call:

```
Dim printthis as String = "Test"
Prn_Str(printthis)
```

My problem is that this only seems to pass the first letter/character of the string--because the printout only shows the first letter of each line/call. I've tried declaring it with a StringBuilder parameter and that didn't work either.

What's the actual way to pass Strings here?

(P.S. Changing the entire app to C++ from VB.Net is not an option because it was previously written for another device using another DLL, and that worked. I'm trying to do a quick port to this new device)

Comment: Wrong [DllImport] declaration, it is CharSet.Ansi

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't set CharSet to ANSI (it wasn't under the CharSets available), but I fixed this by passing it as  ASCII-encoded byte array.

```
<DllImport("VAx_VPOS396_APPAPI.dll", EntryPoint:="Prn_Str")> _
    Private Shared Function Prn_Str(ByVal txt As Byte()) As Integer
    End Function
```

And:

```
Dim printthis as String = "Test"
Dim ascii as new ASCIIEncoding
Dim eb as Byte() = ascii.GetBytes(printtthis)
Prn_Str(eb)
```

Comment: That would take "签购单" and turn it into one or more question marks. Are you sure [CharSet.Ansi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.charset) is not available? [Applies to .NET Framework 4.7.2, 4.7.1, 4.7, 4.6.2, 4.6.1, 4.6, 4.5.2, 4.5.1, 4.5, 4.0, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0, 1.1]